# Is there a way we can encrypt express-session cookies?

Tags: session, encryption, cookies, session-cookies, express-session

The cookies stored by **express-session** are only singed and it doesn't seem secure at all. The cookie is stored in this manner '***s:sessionID.singedData***' but can I use AES256 encryption or any other encryption format so that it adds a layer of security to the cookies stored once we go into production. I have the means to encrypt and decrypt data but I am not sure where exactly to do it. I once tried to encrypt the cookie which was successful but I wasn't able to decrypt it because I couldn't find the relevant function in **express-session** source (BTW I was over-ridding the **express-session** module code.)

Comment: What security benefit do you expect from encrypting the session id?

Comment: Not the session ID but the whole cookie itself. I want to be able to encrypt the whole cookie from ***'s:sessionID.singedData'*** to some random gibberish of encrypted data. When a user who has a basic programming knowledge will be able to exact my session id from the cookie if stored in express-session way.

Comment: It is still not clear what advantage it would have. Signing ensures that the user cannot modify the value of the cookie, so even it the user knows that session ids have a predictable pattern, and is able to guess another session id, the session could not be switched because of the signing. So using encryption in that case is more or less just security through obscurity. You can for sure encrypt the cookie name and value. But what would be the problem in your opinion that the user knows the session id? Figuring out that and which encrypted cookie is a session cookie is not that a huge problem.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What signedData? The session id is already random characters.